# How to download MySQL dump from Windows Azure?

Tags: mysql, azure, dump

I create Web role with Drupal from gallery. How to download database which created automaticaly?

Answer (score 0):

I have't used Azure yet, but I think you can solve that easily by [installing Adminer](http://www.adminer.org) (free).